# Call a Redux Action inside a useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

My objective here is to call an action inside a `useEffect`.

```
const ShowTodos = (props) =>{
   useEffect(()=>{
    props.fetchTodos()
   },[])
} 
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
  return {
    todos:Object.values(state.todos),
    currentUserId:state.authenticate.userId
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{fetchTodos})(ShowTodos)
```

It works fine but I got a warning

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps.
```

But if I'm going to add `props` as my second parameter in my `useEffects` then it will run endlessly.

My first workaround here is to use the `useRef` but it seems that it will always re-render thus re-setup again the useRef which I think is not good in terms of optimization.

```
const ref = useRef();
  ref.current = props;
  console.log(ref)


  useEffect(()=>{
  ref.current.fetchTodos()
  },[])
```

Is there any other workaround here ?

Comment: Dan Abramov also has a deep explanation for this case at https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/. Worth reading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is an `eslint` warning that you get if any of the dependency within `useEffect` is not part of the dependency array.

In your case you are using `props.fetchTodos` inside useEffect and the eslint warning prompts you to provide `props` as a dependency so that if props changes, the useEffect function takes the updated props from its closure.

However since `fetchTodos` is not gonna change in your app lifecycle and you want to run the effect only once you can disable the rule for your case.

```
const ShowTodos = (props) =>{
   const { fetchTodos } = props
   useEffect(()=>{
     fetchTodos()
     // eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
   },[])
} 
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
  return {
    todos:Object.values(state.todos),
    currentUserId:state.authenticate.userId
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{fetchTodos})(ShowTodos)
```

You however can solve the problem without disabling the rule like

```
const ShowTodos = (props) =>{
   const { fetchTodos } = props
   useEffect(()=>{
     fetchTodos()
   },[fetchTodos])
}
```

I however will recommend that you know when exactly should you disable the rule or pass the values to the dependency array.

Comment: @jt25, Well yes you must know when exactly to do what. You can read more about how to take this decision in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786752/how-to-manipulate-context-attach-function-to-context-or-wrap-dispatch-in-hook/55865765#55865765) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-do-i-fix-missing-dependency-in-react-hook-useeffect/55854902#55854902)

Comment: @skyboyer Thanks for the feedback. Yes that was a copy paste error

Answer (score 3):

You have to add fetchTodos to dependencies.

```
const ShowTodos = ({ fetchTodos }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTodos();
  }, [fetchTodos])
  ...
}
```

or like this.

```
const ShowTodos = (props) => {
  const { fetchTodos } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTodos();
  }, [fetchTodos])
  ...
}
```

Comment: why i need do this?

Comment: on including fetchTodos in the dependency list it will be instantiated multiple times that the author might not require.